# Ruby Review class creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, review

The Review class you see below represent a review that a user submitted for a product. Somewhere else in the code, Review.recent is called with a product_id, which is just a unique number that represents a single product. Fill in the code to make it work as expected!

Review.recent - This function should return the 5 most recent reviews (sorted by submit_time) with the specified product_id.

<=> - This special Ruby function is called when comparing two objects for sorting. It returns 1, 0, or +1 depending on whether the object is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object. You'll want to sort items by submit_time so recent items appear first.

set_submit_time - This function is called right before a review is created. We can use Ruby's Time class to set submit_time to now so we know when the review was created.

I'm new to ruby and I want this code for my very important work so how can I complete it help me please!

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  # Every Review has a product_id and submit time
  attr_accessor :product_id
  attr_accessor :submit_time

  # Before the new record is created, we'll call the :set_submit_time method
  before_create :set_submit_time

  def self.recent(product_id)
    # Return only the 5 newest results for this product
    # Reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html
    Review.all
  end

  def <=>(other_review)
    # Implement the comparison function for sorting
    # Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html
  end

  private

  def set_submit_time
    # Set the submit_time
    # Reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Time.html
  end
end
```

Comment: This questions looks like some assignment in school :). 
1. read about https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html , 2.   `self.submit_time <=> other_review.submit_time` 3.  `Review.where(product_id: product_id).order("submit_time desc").limit(5)`

Comment: Is this some kind of interview question or a tutorial you want to complete? Please show what you have written / tried so far and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @nuaky i tried your third point but its throwing me an error that undefined method `where'

Comment: @Stefan You are right somewhere because I got an project related HTML and ruby but i don't knew ruby, this language is new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `self.recent`

This is asking you to **order by `submit_time`** and return the **first 5** results.

To perform the ordering, see: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

To perform the limit, see: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/limit

If you're still stuck on this problem, please show us what you've tried.

2. `<=>`

If you click the link in the comment you provided (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html), the solution is almost identical to that example.

If you're still stuck on this problem, please show us what you've tried.

3. `set_submit_time`

It's worth having a quick look at: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html - to understand what is meant by a callback. Basically, this method is going to get automatically called whenever a new record is created. (You probably could have guessed this, based on the fairly self-explanatory name: `before_create`!)

Again, the first example on that page is almost identical to your scenario. You can use `Time.now` to get the current time.

If you're still stuck on this problem, please show us what you've tried.